# Java Servlet PNG image output display corrupt (not transmitted completely)

Tags: java, servlets, flush, corrupt

I have a problem with some Java servlet I developed a few days ago and finally uploaded it to my test application server.

First I will describe what the Servlet does: Basically it creates a website counter by using two parameters: First parameter is the usernames identifier (username) and the second one is an integer identity which identifies the background image and design which should be applied to the counter, so that the user can change the used counter design without losing his counts. I use a Java servlet to generate the PNG file in these steps:

1. Load counter and design from database to obtain data
2. Load background image from PNG image source file to a BufferedImage
3. Draw the current counter value to the background image using the specified font, xPos, yPos, font size, etc..
4. Write the BufferedImage as PNG file to the servlet output stream specifying the content type is PNG.

The problem here is that the image which will be generated is incomplete (!). I do a flush and close on the output stream buy anyway it is still incomplete. I also tried to leave out all my modifications to draw anything on the Graphics2D of the BufferedImage, but it did not help at all. When I run the same code base in a stand alone application the output image is just fine so I don't think there is a problem with ImageIO or my general code.

Perhaps I missed some mandatory stuff in the servlet output declaration, but I can't find the bug on my own.

Here is the real running application:

http://csz-online.net:8080/CounterBuilder/CounterServlet?name=clemens&layout=61

As you can see the file in incomplete! Firefox for example shows the PNG content it received, but if I download the file Eye of Gnome for example won't display the corrupt file at all! The same image created by the stand alone application is complete and works fine.

THANKS!

Here is the code of the Java servlet processRequest method, which is to be executed on post and get. Since I don't have the original source code at the moment this is what JD-GUI outputs. It pretty looks the same except the exception handling at the end of the method:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException
  {
    ServletContext cntx = getServletContext();
    try
    {
      String creationStr = request.getParameter("layout");
      long cId = Long.valueOf(creationStr).longValue();
      String name = request.getParameter("name");

      Counter counter = this.counterFacade.findByNickname(name);
      Creation creation = this.creationFacade.find(Long.valueOf(cId));

      String filename = cntx.getRealPath(creation.getBackground());
      if (filename == null) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("BG not found: " + creation.getBackground());
      }
      String mime = cntx.getMimeType(filename);

      int cCounter = counter.getCounter() + 1;

      response.setContentType(mime);
      File file = new File(filename);
      response.setContentLength((int)file.length());
      OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();Throwable localThrowable4 = null;
      try
      {
        String fontStr = creation.getFont();
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
        BufferedImage[] digits = new BufferedImage[10];

        image.flush();
        switch (fontStr)
        {
        case "gold": 
          Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
          digits[0] = ImageIO.read(new File(cntx.getRealPath("images/digits/gold/0.png")));
          digits[1] = ImageIO.read(new File(cntx.getRealPath("images/digits/gold/1.png")));
          digits[2] = ImageIO.read(new File(cntx.getRealPath("images/digits/gold/2.png")));
          digits[3] = ImageIO.read(new File(cntx.getRealPath("images/digits/gold/3.png")));
          digits[4] = ImageIO.read(new File(cntx.getRealPath("images/digits/gold/4.png")));
          digits[5] = ImageIO.read(new File(cntx.getRealPath("images/digits/gold/5.png")));
          digits[6] = ImageIO.read(new File(cntx.getRealPath("images/digits/gold/6.png")));
          digits[7] = ImageIO.read(new File(cntx.getRealPath("images/digits/gold/7.png")));
          digits[8] = ImageIO.read(new File(cntx.getRealPath("images/digits/gold/8.png")));
          digits[9] = ImageIO.read(new File(cntx.getRealPath("images/digits/gold/9.png")));
          drawNumbersToImage(g, digits, cCounter, creation.getxPos(), creation.getyPos());
          break;
        default: 
          Font font = new Font(creation.getFont(), 0, creation.getFontSize());
          FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(null, true, true);
          TextLayout layout = new TextLayout(String.valueOf(cCounter), font, frc);
          Graphics2D h = image.createGraphics();
          h.setColor((Color)Color.class.getField(creation.getColor()).get(null));
          layout.draw(h, creation.getxPos(), creation.getyPos());
          h.dispose();
        }
        counter.setCounter(cCounter);
        this.counterFacade.edit(counter);

        ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", out);

        out.flush();
        out.close();
      }
      catch (Throwable localThrowable1)
      {
        localThrowable4 = localThrowable1;throw localThrowable1;
      }
      finally
      {
        if (out != null) {
          if (localThrowable4 != null) {
            try
            {
              out.close();
            }
            catch (Throwable x2)
            {
              localThrowable4.addSuppressed(x2);
            }
          } else {
            out.close();
          }
        }
      }
    }
    catch (IOException|NoSuchFieldException|SecurityException|IllegalArgumentException|IllegalAccessException ex)
    {
      ex.printStackTrace();

      response.setContentType("text/HTML");
      PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();Throwable localThrowable3 = null;
      try
      {
        writer.print("Could not generate counter due to missing or invalid parameters <b>bg</b> and <b>name</b>.");
      }
      catch (Throwable localThrowable2)
      {
        localThrowable3 = localThrowable2;throw localThrowable2;
      }
      finally
      {
        if (writer != null) {
          if (localThrowable3 != null) {
            try
            {
              writer.close();
            }
            catch (Throwable x2)
            {
              localThrowable3.addSuppressed(x2);
            }
          } else {
            writer.close();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: no ideas?! It MUST be possible to solve this problem :(

Comment: I am having the same problem with an update utility program that I wrote.